# move the directory to Recycle Bin/Trash

Tags: c++, recycle-bin

ALL,

I'm trying to move either the file or a directory to a Recycle Bin/Trash.

Here is my code:

```
SHFILEOPSTRUCT fileOp;
memset( fileOp, 0, sizeof( SHFILEOPSTRUCT ) );
fileOp.hwnd = NULL;
fileOp.wFunc = FO_DELETE;
wxString temp = fileName + '\0';
fileOp.pFrom = temp.c_str();
fileOp.pTo = NULL;
fileOp.fFlags = FOF_ALLOWUNDO | FOF_NOERRORUI | FOF_NOCONFIRMATION | FOF_SILENT;
int res = SHFileOperation( &fileOp );
if( res != 0 )
    printf( _ ( "Failed to move file '%s' to Recycle Bin" ), fileName.c_str() );
else
    result = true;
```

The fileName variable has a value of "C:\temp\testfolder" and the "testfolder" has 1 file in it.

Upon the execution the SHFileOperation() does not return 0, but gives 124, which according to the MSDN is "The path in the source or destination or both was invalid.".

Now the question: does this mean I can't put the non-empty folder into the Recycle Bin/Trash? If the answer is yes - what would be the easiest way of modifying the code to account for it? Or maybe there is a different API call?

Thank you.

Comment: FO_DELETE does work on non-empty directories. Wild guess: Maybe you have no read permissions on the folder in question? Do other operations work on the directory?

Comment: @LukasBoersma, I just checked. Doing right click on the directory and selecting "Properties" I see the option "Read Only" is in the 3rd state. OK, so how do I fix it?

Comment: @ChristopherOicles it is UNICODE one. But removing the file does work OK. Directory is failing. Trying to remove it from Explorer is also fail.

Answer (score 1):

I have run into a similar problem where `SHFileOperation` returned 2 (`ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`).

After checking the documentation (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-_shfileopstructa ) it seems the problem is that the `pFrom` parameter actually represents a list of filenames, each one is null-terminated, but the final filename is terminated with an extra null.  So I expect in your case you need to change this line:

```
wxString temp = fileName + '\0' + '\0'; // double terminated
```